# Adding files into a folder inside a zip file in c#

Tags: c#, zip, compression, archive, c#-ziparchive

My code to zip files is as follows

```
ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(destToZip, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
zip.CreateEntry("pubEd/");

string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dirToZip);
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    zip.CreateEntryFromFile(fileName,Path.GetFileName(fileName), CompressionLevel.Optimal);

zip.Dispose();
```

In the second line of the code once after creating a zip file I create a folder with a name pubEd inside the zip file.

In the next line I am adding files to the zip folder.

What is happening is files get added to the zip directly.

I want to add these files inside the directory which I created inside the zip.

How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe check out http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Comment: Also try wrapping your `ZipArchive Zip=` code around a `using(){}` this way you do not have to directly call the `Dispose()` Method
[ZipFileExtensions.CreateEntryFromFile MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it you would change`Path.GetFileName(fileName)` to `"pubEd/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName)`.  And get rid of the second line.  Thats just based on my reading of the documentation.  I have not actually tried it.