# How to add a file to a folder inside a zip in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, zip, php-ziparchive

I need to read a file from a folder and place it a folder which is inside a zip in .NET core.

I searched for this and found [Adding files into a folder inside a zip file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805784/adding-files-into-a-folder-inside-a-zip-file-in-c-sharp#) but this is not working for me.

My code to zip files is:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("Test.zip", FileMode.Create))
using (var zip = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    zip.CreateEntry("Folder1 /"); 
}// working till here, Creates a zip and then creates Folder 1 inside Test.zip`
```

But I need to read a file from "C:\Files" and place it inside 'Folder1'. The file gets added to zip but not inside 'Folder1'.

Comment: What error you are facing?

Comment: I didn't face any error.I tried using `zip.CreateEntryFromFile(SourceFilePath,"FileName",CompressionLevel.Optimal);` But this is creating the entry inside test.zip.But i need to add this entry to "Test.zip/Folder1".

Comment: can you share your code where you adding your entry in Folder1

Comment: `var zipPath = configuration.GetValue<string>(Constant.AppSettings.FileDownloadLocation);
                var fileToReadPath = configuration.GetValue<string>(Constant.AppSettings.TestFileLocation);

                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToReadPath, "NewEntry", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                }`
I tried to do this in this way

Comment: which path you are passing in fileToReadPath

Comment: From where i am reading file i.e D:\TestFiles

Comment: In this code where you are adding new entry

Comment: The CreateEntryFromFile method creates a new entry in the directory where we are currently at.

Comment: Where you are passing your destination folder path

Comment: I figured it out `archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToReadPath, @"Folder1/FileName", CompressionLevel.Fastest);` will create folder 'Folder1' add then add entry inside that folder.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to do the trick:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceFileName = "MyFile.txt";
        string sourceFolder = @"C:\Files";
        string zipFilePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Files", "Test.zip");

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.Combine(sourceFolder, sourceFileName), $"Folder1\\{sourceFileName}");
        }
    }
}
```